# jQuery selector not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

sample html:

```
<tr>
    <td class="hidden tblLnk">8163</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="hidden tblLnk">8163</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="hidden tblLnk">8164</td> 
</tr>
```

this method should return a unique array of text from rows with a specific td class.  { 8163, 8164 } in our sample.

works in ffs and chrome but not in ie8 or safari.  can you spot the problem?

```
function getUniqueIds()
{
     var tblLnks = new Array();

     $('td.tblLnk').each(function()
     {
        tblLnks.push($(this).text().trim());
     });

     return tblLnks.unique();
}
```

Comment: Can you post an html snippet too?

Comment: And the code for your unique()-method.

Comment: ie error:

Message: Object doesn't support this property or method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this:

```
$(this).text().trim()
```

should be this:

```
$.trim($(this).text());
```

If your intention is to us jQuery's trim() function.

Comment: As an addendum, String.trim() is only available in JavaScript 1.8.1/ECMAScript 5, which is implemented by Firefox 3.5.  This explains the differences:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim

Answer (score 1):

1st: There is no native `unique()` method on the `Array` object in JavaScript that works in all A-grade browsers as of today. So if this is your intention, please post that code aswell.

2nd: If you refer to the [`unique()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/) method of jQuery you better read up on the description of that method. This method can´t be called on the `Array` object. It takes an `Array` object of DOM elements as a paramenter, e.g.:

```
$.unique(myArrayOfDomElements);
```

Comment: i added a unique function.


Array.prototype.unique =
  function() {
    var a = [];
    var l = this.length;
    for(var i=0; i<l; i++) {
      for(var j=i+1; j<l; j++) {
        // If this[i] is found later in the array
        if (this[i] === this[j])
          j = ++i;
      }
      a.push(this[i]);
    }
    return a;
  };